# Fetch data of one model in another model without association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have two models and without using association i want to fetch all data of one model in another view in a drop down list. how could i? 
like,

i have admin controller/model and service controller/model, now i want to fetch all datas of admin in service'view part in drop down list...without using association?

Comment: how is it possible?? without creating instance of another model inside the current model?

Comment: <%=f.collection_select :activ,Admin.all,:facility,:facility %>

where :activ here we want to save our data Admin.all from here we wnt to fetch all data :facility which part we want to save/cal

Answer (score 0):

I got solution:

```
<%=f.collection_select :activ,Admin.all,:facility,:facility %>
```

Where:

1. `:activ`: here we want to save our data.
2. `Admin.all`: from here we wnt to fetch all data
3. `:facility`: which part we want to save/call